# Есть ли альтернатива методу friends.areFriends из VK.Api, не требующая токена?

Tags: vkontakte-api

`friends.areFriends` - есть такой метод у меня, беру текущего юзера, проверяю есть ли он в друзьях либо подписчиках у массива юзеров.

> Возвращает информацию о том, добавлен ли текущий пользователь в друзья у указанных пользователей.
>   Также возвращает информацию о наличии исходящей или входящей заявки в друзья (подписки).

Приложение заблокировали. Перешел на uLogin, не знаю как быть, чем заменить.

Может, всё-таки и uLogin даёт права и токен? Или, может, методами другими заменить, не требующими токен?

Если можно как-нибудь, объясните, пожалуйста.

Я думаю можно сделать как-то изощренно, только боюсь оказаться не прав.

Comment: Из всего текста непонятно, что вы хотите сделать. Найти альтернативу методу `friends.areFriends`?

Comment: именно, я думаю это можно сделать несколькими другими методами возможно

Comment: uLogin не отдаёт токены. Зарегистрируйте новый аккаунт ВК, получите его токен и подставьте в запрос.

Comment: у меня проект. сферы накрутки, у других как-то всё работает на методах не требующих токен. авторизация у них на юлогин. вот и спрашиваю